# IAnnotation transform method is not disabling the test in testng

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng.xml, testng-annotation-test

Here my intention is , Based on the before method condition the `@Test` method needs to enabled or disabled But in the below code even though I am passing the test case name its not getting skipped ? Can anyone suggest me solution?

I need the `BeforeTestMethod` to check some logic in my actual code and based on that I have to enable the `@Test` in the class file

```
public class ListnerClass implements IAnnotationTransformer {
public static String  testName;
public void transform(ITestAnnotation iTest, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method method) {
    if(method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(testName)) {
        iTest.setEnabled(false);
    }
    
}

public class TestNGTest3 {
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(Method result) {
    System.out.println("This is the before Method getting name "+result.getName());
    if(result.getName().contains("3")) 
       {
        ListnerClass.testName=result.getName();

    }
}

@Test
public void testMethod3() {
    System.out.println("This is the Method of Method");
}

@Test
public void testMethod4() {

    System.out.println("Hi");
}


    
}
```

`TestNG.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name=" Regression Suite">
    <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.listners.ListnerClass" />
    </listeners>
    <test thread-count="1" name="Test">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.test.TestNGTest3" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Output:

```
This is the before Method getting name testMethod3
This is the Method of Method
This is the before Method getting name testMethod4
Hi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have achieve my intention with the help of the below post.

[Why is throw new SkipException() skipping all my methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888283/why-is-throw-new-skipexception-skipping-all-my-methods)

Here is an working sample:

```
 public class TestClassTest {
 static String name;
 static int i=0;
`public static String testmethod() {        
    List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Raja");
    list.add("Raju");
    list.add("Raj");
    name=list.get(i);
    i++;
    return name;
    
    
}


 public class DependsOnMethodClass extends TestClassTest {

@BeforeMethod()
public void beforecaller(Method m) {    
if(!testmethod().equals("Raju")) {
    System.out.println("This is the method going to be skipped
"+m.getName());
    throw new SkipException("Data provided is not matching");


}
else {
    System.out.println("This is the method not skipped"+m.getName());
}
```

}

```
@Test
public void getCall() {
System.out.println("This is the getCall method");
```

}

```
@Test()
public void getCall1() {
System.out.println("This is the getCall1 method");
}
}
```

Update of TestNG xml: (Important Change)
Adding the parameter  configfailurepolicy="continue" will continue the test even we
are throwing skip exception.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" configfailurepolicy="continue">
<test thread-count="5" name="Test">
<classes>
  <class name="com.testng.newsuite.DependsOnMethodClass"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Output:
This is the method going to be skipped getCall
This is the method not skipped getCall1
This is the getCall1 method
```